# Android Java how to make single bar graphic

Tags: java, android, graphic

I need to show a "graphic" with part of the box colored in. 
In the box it it will have text, but then I want to be able to put a color on the background to show how high the numbers are.  see the graphic I made in excel. (I guess I am not allowed to upload a picture.  So not sure how to explain this..
[Click here to see the excel picture](http://qa.mark-systems.com:83/Capture2.jpg)

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the colour to dynamically change colour for each value?  Or are you okay with just having a few colour "levels" (e.g. red, yellow, green).

The easier route would be to just have a few set colours and create those gradients in photoshop and then apply those textures to the back of an ImageView using the background attribute.

Here are some tutorials on how views work: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: I need to be able to change how big the box is dynamically. so as the data is filling up the bar that I am drawing would be bigger...

Answer (score 3):

You can simply make an XML Drawable, something like this (save under res/drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#FF00FF00"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FF000000"
        />
/>
```

then just use a TextView, with this Drawable set as your `android:background` attribute.

Comment: How would I change the size of this dynamically?  Like if the data was 50% I would like to fill the box to 50% of the width.

Comment: Ah I see what you're looking for. You should try looking into using the ProgressBar widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.htmlI haven't used it, so I can't offer any specific advice, but that's the type of thing you should probably use for this.